# can't get rich:select trigger webflow action

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, spring-webflow

This perfectly worked with jsf1.2 and richfaces 3.3 (countries list to filter by):

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="countriesList"
                     value="#{filter.country}"
                     converter="countriesConverter">
        <a4j:support event="onchange"
                     action="filter"
                     reRender="...." />
        <f:selectItems value="#{service.countries}"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
```

a webflow transition was exectued on selected country change

```
<transition on="filter" validate="false" bind="false">
...
 </transition>
```

Now I want to do the same with JSF 2.1 and RF 4. I tried

```
<rich:select id="countriesList" 
             value="#{filter.country}" 
             converter="#{countriesConverter}" >
     <a4j:ajax event="selectitem" action="filter" reRender="..." execute="@form"/>
     <f:selectItems value="#{service.countries}"/>
</rich:select>
```

but this doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Best regards, Eugene.

Comment: There's no `reRender` attribute in `<a4j:ajax>` of RF 4.x.

Comment: found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860142/how-to-execute-transition-on-value-change-in-hselectonemenu. It works, but, is it really that bad? Now way to trigger webflow transition from select without java code?